# Html - padding - doesnt work as intended

Tags: html, padding

probably silly question, but i need your help. 
I have a div and text inside. I need to adjust text inside div via padding, but when i apply padding command, it do nothing.

This is part of my code https://jsfiddle.net/oje_cz/am7twxmp/

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<div id="footer-3" 
            style="height: 80px;
            float: left;
            width: 250px;
            text-align: right;
            background: rgba(226, 4, 28, 1);">

    <t style="font-family: arial;
        color: white;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding-top: 5px;">
                Obchodní identifikační údaje:<br>
                IČ: 28 44 18 77<br>
                DIČ: CZ 28 44 18 77
    </t>
</div id="footer-3">

</html>
```

How to use padding to make it work? I want move rows more far from top. Thx for answers

Comment: Not sure why 't' tag (?!), but, add display: block to it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/am7twxmp/3/)

Just add `display: block;` in **style** to `<t>`

```
<t style="font-family: arial;
        color: white;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        display: block;">
```

**OR** replace `<t>` by `<div>`